# Link for username & password dataset

Tags: passwords

I want to know links to download "username and password" dataset for my research.
I want to create a big dataset of 100-200MB for my research.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no single or best answer to this question.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions of the type "where can I find X?" are off topic.